# Is the gist/importance of pointers due to the fact that non-primitive data requires multiple memory blocks?

Tags: c, pointers

I feel like this is the final piece in me understanding pointers. "Why are pointers important?"

(I mean, I'm sure there's a lot of reasons, but is this not the biggest?)

For awhile I've understood that `int num = 5;` was done because `num` is a way for us to refer to the value stored at whatever memory address we put `5` into. If I then do `num = 10;` it updates that memory address to store `10` instead, and `num` still points to the value at that particular memory address. Am I right so far?

So I was confused why we wouldn't just do `char str = "string"`, or the same for other objects. Is it because what we're trying to store cannot be stored in one memory block, unlike `int` and other primitives?

We do it because we need *multiple* memory blocks, and pointers effectively give us a reference to where it *starts* and then we can go as far as we need to collect all the data needed for the object?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the importance of pointers due to the fact that non-primitive data requires multiple memory blocks? We need multiple memory blocks, and pointers effectively give us a reference to where it starts and then we can go as far as we need to collect all the data needed for the object?

No. What you are describing is the important of *arrays*.

So what is the importance of pointers?

Suppose you have some data:

```
12
```

What can you do with that data?  You can store it in a storage location and fetch it from that location later when you need it.

```
int height = 12;
```

You can pass it as a value to a method:

```
doit(12);
```

You can compare it for equality with other values:

```
if (height == 13)
```

and a few other things as well, but these are some of the big ones.

Well, the same thing is true of pointers. Pointers are values, so they can be stored, fetched, passed and compared. But any addressable storage location can be turned into a pointer. So this is the power of pointers in C: **they allow you to treat storage locations like any other data.**

Answer (score 0):

> and num still points to the value at that particular memory address

No, because `num` is not a pointer. I'm counting beans here, but that's important to get your ideas right. When you define a variable `num`, the compiler assigns the name `num` to a memory address, which stays valid as long as the variable is in scope - for the whole program, if it's a global variable, or until your function returns, for local variables.

Objects can be any size, for example, a structure might consist of a lot of elements. And something like

```
char c[100]="string"
```

is perfectly valid; there are no pointers involved (yet).

One of the reasons why you need pointers is when you call a function. Normally, all parameters to a function are called by value. So, if you have a function

void swap (int x, int y) {
        int temp=x;
        x=y;
        y=temp;
    }

and call it

```
int a=3;
int b=5;
swap(a, b);
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

you'll get output values 3 and 5 - the variables have, obviously, not been swapped. The reason for this is the compiler creates copies of the variables and passes the copies to swap.

Now, if you want to tell the compiler "I don't want copies, i want swap to change the memory locations that i named `a` and `b`", you need pointers:

void swap (int *x, int *y) {
        int temp=*x;
        *x=*y;
        *y=temp;
    }

```
int a=3;
int b=5;
swap(&a, &b);
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

The `&` operator tells the compiler "I want the memory address that i named a, not the value that i wrote into that memory address". Within the swap function, the `*` means "x is not the value that i want, it's the address of the memory i really want to change - the variable that belongs to the function that called me". Other programming languages like pascal call this "call by reference", vs. "call by value" in C.

Now your language *has* pointers. Let's reconsider strings, and arrays.

If i call a function

```
myfunction("Thisisaverylongstringthatjustwontendnoway....")
```

the call by value has to copy a lot of bytes from the caller to the callee, which is inefficient. So, one of the design decisions in C was:

> Whenever a function calls another, passing an array as a parameter, the array is not passed by value, instead, we automatically pass a pointer the the start of the array, making it a call by reference.

So, in function calls, arrays (and strings are just a special case of an array) are always passed as pointer. Which is why, in C, you have to learn about pointers quite soon; you can get along without them much longer in, say, Pascal. Or Java (where, behind the scenes, you work with pointers all the time when you're working with Objects, but Java hides that from you).

And this is why pointers are, very often, introduced shortly after arrays and strings, when you learn C. As soon as you know what a function is, and what an array, or a string, is, you need to know about pointers or you won't get functions and arrays together.

Your last sentence about "multiple memory blocks" isn't correct in the sense that anything that's larger than a few bytes needs a pointer - structures do not - but, in most cases, your program will just be faster with pointers. If you have two strings, each 100 bytes long, and want to swap them, you'd need to do a lot of copying stuff around. Just swapping the pointers is much faster (typically, a pointer needs 4-8 bytes), so as soon as you're dealing with larger objects, you *want* to deal with pointers pointing to them, for efficiency reasons.

Now i haven't even begun with dynamic memory allocation .. but i guess my answer is large enough already.